# How can we configure a TypeORM ViewEntity's ViewColumn to be of JSON type?

Tags: typeorm

I am creating a `@ViewEntity()` with TypeORM on MySQL in which I directly select a JSON column. The view is correct and just a normal SQL view.

The column definition for the view class looks as such:

`@ViewColumn() document: Estimate;`

where `Estimate` is an interface specifying the data shape of the JSON, although I have tried `Estimate | Object` as well. The entities retrieved by the Repository are always having the document property as a `string`, evidently the ORM is not parsing the JSON. Therefore I am having to do some annoying `JSON.parse()` and mutating the retrieved record before responding to requests.

`ViewColumnOptions` only takes a property of `name`, so I cannot specify `{ type: 'json' }` as I would on a conventional `@Entity()`'s `@Column()`. Are JSON columns in TypeORM views even implemented? I have been unable to find results in the docs nor on the github issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not well-covered in the documentation.

Turns out you can just use a `@Column()` decorator within a view, so my solution for the above is to specify my view's column definition as

`@Column({ type: 'json' }) document: Estimate;`

instead of as

`@ViewColumn() document: Estimate;` in the original question.

Furthermore, for anyone who may stumble upon this later, if you want to do relations against your view, you must decorate at least one column in your view as `@PrimaryColumn()` in order for TypeORM to formulate the SQL properly. Again, this is not covered in the docs; you could be forgiven after having read them for believing that only `@ViewColumn()` is valid within a `@ViewEntity()`.

Your relations inside the `@ViewEntity()` will need to look as such for an example `Customer` relation:

```
@ManyToOne(() => Customer)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'customerId' })
customer: Customer;
@ViewColumn() customerId: string;
```

In the above I have selected in my view's SQL `customerId` alias and you can see I must specify that both as the name of the `@JoinColumn()` as well as a `@ViewColumn()` after the property declaration of the related entity.